# Shadow characters in Vim editor that do not appear when I read the file on another editor

Tags: vim

Every now and then I have characters that stay in the buffer when they should be gone since they have been deleted from the file. There seems to be a lack of synchronicity between the Vim editor and the file it's reading from. For example, I tried to write the word "location" and made a typo, instead I wrote "locaation". I went back to the first 'a' and deleted both 'a's by mistake. As a result the old 'n' at the end of the word stayed at the previous position, whilst the new 'n' went where it should be (i.e. "loction n"). This happens in all kinds of files and this one was a .md. When I read the file in my browser there was no additional `n`.

[image: What I get in the Vim editor]

[image: What I get in Google Chrome with the markdown viewer extension]

It only happens in Vim; when I use NeoVim everything works fine. I have to use Vim though, because of some crucial plugins that do not exist in NeoVim...

I tried to change the colorscheme and change to one of Vim's default, but I still get the same bug. I searched for a solution on Google to no avail as I don't really know how to formulate the problem...

EDIT: As requested, below is the output of `:version`.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Sep 30 2023 05:45:56)
macOS version - arm64
Included patches: 1-1894
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
-arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
-balloon_eval_term -gettext           +num64             +textobjects
-browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     -perl              +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        -vartabs
+clipboard         -keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            -profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      -langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           -python3           +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
-- More --
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add the output of `:version` to your question. Thank you.

Comment: Use Vim's issue tracker.

Comment: @Friedrich it shows 9.0.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with `vim --clean`? If no, one of your settings is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this behaviour.  Maybe you can do a `:redraw` in command mode or  in normal mode.

In Vim:

`:redraw` is a command mode shortcut that forces the editor to refresh the screen and redraw all the content. This can be useful if the display appears garbled or outdated.

`<C-L>` (Control+L) is the equivalent key combination in normal mode for the same functionality.